# Did the Power Rangers ever violate their rules?

Tags: power-rangers

The Power Rangers have a pretty simple code, consisting of three rules (paraphrased):

- Never use your power for personal gain
- Never be the ones to escalate a battle
- Always protect your secret identity

When Zordon officially inducts Tommy as the Sixth Ranger, he reiterates these rules and warns him that breaking them will lead to the loss of his powers.  With as long as the show has been around, has there ever been a time when some iteration of the Power Rangers broke the rules?  If so, were they punished for it by the loss of their powers?

Comment: Which power rangers are you addressing in the question?

Answer (score 2):

> With as long as the show has been around, has there ever been a time
>   when some iteration of the Power Rangers broke the rules? If so, were
>   they punished for it by the loss of their powers?

From the [IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106064/trivia?tab=gf&ref_=tt_trv_gf#plot_hole) of the original Power Rangers show:

> Secret identities are traditionally used to protect a hero and their
>   loved one's from their enemies, yet the identity of the Power Rangers
>   is ONLY a secret to their loved ones - literally every enemy they face
>   (in this and following series') knows who they are. In fact, they
>   quite regularly form plans based on an individual Rangers' phobias or
>   personal items.

I haven't seen any iteration other than the first show, and haven't seen the movie, this is the best I could find..

Comment: I happened to catch a few episodes of some of the newer iterations while round a friend's house, and I can confirm that the Rangers don't seem to care about their secret identities at all. They will literally run up to the Monster of the Week in their civilian guises, come out with some pithy one-liner, and then transform right in front of it.